# SQL Compact 3.5 attach multiple DB/ cross-db query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce

Is it possible to attach multiple DBs to SQL CE 3.5 (Compact edition) e.g. MasterData.sdf, Orders.sdf and apply queries against them e.g.:
select Orders.iOrderID, Orders.cItemID, MasterData.cItemDesc
from Orders.CustomerOrder as Orders
left join MasterData.Items as Items on Orders.cItemID = Items.cItemID

I need this because of sync optimization (many small databases vs. one big database).

---

Is there any other solution to *merge* two (many) sdf-s into one ?

Comment: You can merge using my scripting tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible - but you could load each table as a list of business objects, and use LINQ to query cross these collections. (Requires more memory)